# How to plot zero variance data in histogram in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

python version == 3.9.2

matplotlib version == 3.4.1

seaborn version == 0.11.1

pandas version == 1.2.4

Hi,
I'm trying to plot a dataset with zero variance, so basically just a list of zeros (or in my case 0.0). But I get nonsensical results. If I try this:

```
df_tan = pd.read_csv(path_tan, sep="\t", index_col=None)
plt.xticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sb.set_style("white")
sb.histplot(df_tan["tan_bin_2"], bins=20)
```

[Result of previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rWY9.png)

Then I get one column in the histogram corresponding to N occurrences of zeros in my dataframe. But the whole x-axis is shifted to the right. So the "zero" column isn't at the left side (or the beginning) of the figure, it's in the middle.

What I really need is for this to work:

```
def plot_graphs_hist(path_tan, path_dice, mol_id, ref_mol_var, data_type):
    df_tan = pd.read_csv(path_tan, sep="\t", index_col=None)
    df_dice = pd.read_csv(path_dice, sep="\t", index_col=None)

    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    plt.figure(figsize=(19,9))
    sb.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.25)
    sb.set_style("white")

    plt.subplot(2,3,1)
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_tan["tan_bin_2"], bins=20)

    plt.subplot(2,3,2)
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_tan["tan_bin_3"], bins=20)

    plt.subplot(2,3,3)
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_tan["tan_GP2D"], bins=20)

    plt.subplot(2,3,4)
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_dice["dice_bin_2"], bins=20)

    plt.subplot(2,3,5)
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_dice["dice_bin_3"], bins=20)

    plt.subplot(2,3,6) #sometimes has zero variance
    plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
    sb.histplot(df_dice["dice_GP2D"], bins=20)
```

And it does. Except for a few cases where the last subplot takes input data that has zero variance. In that case, all other subplots are correct but the last one has no columns in the figure and the axes are shifted so that they have 0 in the middle (see the picture).

[Example of subplots with zero variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvyZc.png)

I'm no statistician so I don't know why having zero variance is a problem here. I previously tried to only plot KDE distribution but I got a warning about my data having zero variance and therefore the distribution was skipped and not drawn at all.

`df_tan` and `df_dice` contain Tanimoto and Dice similarity so they assume values from 0 to 1.

Comment: Default a histogram will create evenly-spaced bins between the smallest and the largest value.  If the smallest and the largest value are equal, there isn't much histogram to draw. Also, with only one value, the kdeplot would be an infinitely high, infinitely narrow curve, which is hard to draw.  For consistent histograms, you could try `sns.histplot(..., binrange=[0,1])`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I now have one high column (bin) at the beginning of the figure.